# how to fetch all names from this json string

Tags: java, json

Can anyone help me to fetch the names from the json string

```
FileDatas[] respone = new Gson().fromJson(outputTemplate, FileDatas[].class);
for (FileDatas s : respone) {
    template_name = s.getName();
    System.out.println("Template Name : "+template_name);
    templateName.addItem(template_name);
}
```

Comment: Json String is :  [{"longName":"Java Folder"},{"longName":"Java_TEMPLATE"},{"longName":"Program"},{"longName":"Test Template"},{"longName":"test_template"},{"longName":"Java"},{"longName":"javaTest2"},{"longName":"TestJavaF"},{"longName":"javaTemplateTest"}]

Comment: I am getting null in string template_name , FileDatas is my pojo .

Comment: Please format your code properly and edit your question instead of writing comments.

Comment: Is the json field ``longName`` mapped to the java field that's returned by ``getName()``?

Comment: Thanks f1sh : i got the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the variable name longName should exact the same in pojo class as a variable for eg if i want to fetch the data longName from json string then in pojo class i will initialise the variable as private String longName .